# How to best handle Dictionary<> for display with ServiceStack.Api.Swagger?

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I've got a class that basically looks like this :

```
public class Project : IReturn<CreateProjectResponse>
{
   public Dictionary<string, string> DataBag { get; set; }
}
```

When accessing the Swagger doc generated web site, I get the following for my service method...

```
Project {
   dataBag (Dictionary`2)
}

Dictionary`2 {
  comparer (IEqualityComparer`1),
  count (int),
  keys (KeyCollection),
  values (ValueCollection),
  item (string)
}

IEqualityComparer`1 {
}

KeyCollection {
  count (int)
}

ValueCollection {
  count (int)
}
```

Is there a way to get a cleaner documentation? The resulting JSON is only after all...

```
{
   "dataBag": {
      "someKey": "some value",
      "someOtherKey": "some other value"
    }
}
```